# Rational number in form $(a^x+b^y)/(c^z+d^w)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, perfect-powers

> Find all positive integers $(x,y,z,w)$ such that for any positive rational number $r=p/q$, there exist positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ for which $$r=\frac{a^x+b^y}{c^z+d^w}.$$

For instance, for $(x,y,z,w)=(2,3,5,7)$ we can take $$(a,b,c,d)=(p^3q^7,p^5q^2,pq^3,p^2q),$$ which means that $(2,3,5,7)$ is valid.

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn), $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(3,3,3,3)$ are valid, while $(\text{even, even, even, even})$ is invalid.

Of course, this question is a generalization of the linked question, which is still unsolved. But any partial (positive or negative) results on other values of $(x,y,z,w)$ would also be interesting as well.

Comment: I assume x,y,z,w are >1