# Show that any positive rational number can be expressed as $\frac{a^3+b^3}{c^3+d^3}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Show that any positive rational number can be expressed as $$\frac{a^3+b^3}{c^3+d^3}$$

Perhaps the statement means that for every two positive integers $m$ and $n$, there exists a $k$ such that $mk$ and $nk$ both can be expressed as the sum of 2 cubes.

Personally, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: see [Representing every positive rational number in the form of $(a^n+b^n)/(c^n+d^n)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn).