# Representation of rational number in special form

Tags: number-theory

Prove that any positive rational number $\dfrac{m}{n}$ can be represented as $\dfrac{a^3+b^3}{c^3+d^3}$ where $(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{N}^4$.

Can anyone give a full solution please? Unfortunately I have no idea in particular for $m=2$ and $n=1$.

Comment: Why downvote???

Comment: Not the downvoter, but after 2000+ rep points surely you can recognize when a question is lacking any context (and also notice that it is phrased like a stereotypical homework request)?

Comment: see [Representing every positive rational number in the form of $(a^n+b^n)/(c^n+d^n)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn)

Comment: @mathlove, Thanks for link!

Comment: The smallest solution for $m/n=2$ comes from $1456/728$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, How you get these values? Can you explain it more detailed please?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003325/b003325.txt has a list of numbers that are the sum of two positive cubes. Go down the list, looking at the even ones, checking to see whether half the number is on the list.