# rational numbers of the form $\frac{a^3+b^3}{c^3+d^3}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

Show that all positive rational numbers can be written in the form

$$\frac{a^3+b^3}{c^3+d^3}$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers.

Comment: The answer is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn?rq=1

Comment: See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19763p131812

Comment: Thanks all of your comments, they really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Xam commented on 2017 Feb 13 that an answer was given [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19763p131812) by zabelman on 2005 Dec 17. Also on 2017 Feb 13, timon92 mentioned the following answer found in a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn) by mathlove on 2015 Mar 11:

> For **every positive rational number** $r$, there exists a set of four **positive integers** $(a,b,c,d)$ such that 
>   $$r=\frac{a^\color{red}{3}+b^\color{red}{3}}{c^\color{red}{3}+d^\color{red}{3}}.$$
>
> For $r=p/q$ where $p,q$ are positive integers, we can take 
>   $$(a,b,c,d)=(3ps^3t+9qt^4,\ 3ps^3t-9qt^4,\ 9qst^3+ps^4,\ 9qst^3-ps^4)$$
>   where $s,t$ are positive integers such that $3\lt r\cdot(s/t)^3\lt 9$.
>
> For $r=2014/89$, for example, since we have $(2014/89)\cdot(2/3)^3\approx 6.7$, taking $(p,q,s,t)=(2014,89,2,3)$ gives us $$\frac{2014}{89}=\frac{209889^3+80127^3}{75478^3+11030^3}.$$